# How to UNNEST a REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL in BigQuery?

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

We are attempting to get a multi-row/one-row-per-item extract from a blob of text in BigQuery.

We seem to be able to only extract the first item in the array using UNNEST - whereas we would like every item to be on its own row.

Here's the code that duplicates the problem.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT 
    REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(blob, r"(.+)\s{2,}") AS antibiotic
  FROM
  (

    SELECT """
      Amoxicillin/Clavulanic Acid    I
      Ampicillin                     R
      Penicillin                     S
      """ 
    AS blob
  )  
), UNNEST(antibiotic) unnested_antibiotic
```

What are we missing?

Comment: clarify please - what is expected result

Comment: why not just do `SELECT unnested_antibiotic FROM ...` in most outer SELECT? I don't see the problem. please calrify

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant IMHO you are a saint answering these BigQuery questions so consistently and rapidly. You are right. I just realized there is no problem with the code. Somehow the UI in BigQuery got set to display_rows = 1 so it was only showing one row of results on the page rather than many like it typically does which threw me off. The code is correct. Is the right SO practice for me to delete the question or answer it myself? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `SELECT unnested_antibiotic FROM ...` instead of `SELECT * FROM ...` in most outer SELECT statement